# Get jqgrid DOM ID from event triggers

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm extending jqgrid default options:

```
$.extend(
    $.jgrid.defaults,
    {
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader:
        {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        },
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 20,
        recordtext: 'record',
        loadtext: 'loading',
        imgpath: 'path',
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,
        postData: { random: Math.random() },
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        beforeRequest: function() { OnBeforeRequestFunct(); }, 
        onPaging: function() { OnPagingPersonalize(); },
        gridComplete: function() { if(editedRowIds.length > 0)
                                        refreshSelection(); 
                                 }
    }
);
```

So i need to pass caller jqgrid id to OnBeforeRequestFunct() when trigger event **beforeRequest** is fired from grids.

Comment: Anyone ? Or least tel me concept how can i do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to pass the ID of the grid's DOM element? Have you tried:

```
OnBeforeRequestFunct(this.id);
```

Comment: :) thanks, I did test it before with console.log(this), it returned just "{}", which i didn't look inside d :)

Thanks again